# Nest Camera: writing is_streaming field has no effect

Tags: nest-api

When I try to change the is_streaming field of a Nest camera, the request does not return any error but the field is not changed.

In the API docs, I noticed it says

> You must ask the user if it's ok to change streaming status (turn the
>   camera on/off). The user must agree to this change before your product
>   can change this camera status.
>   https://developer.nest.com/documentation/api-reference/overview#isstreaming-cam

so I wonder if this rule is enforced and how?

I don't own a Nest Camera, I'm testing with the Nest Home Simulator in which you can create fake cameras, so maybe I'm not seeing everything as a real user would.

Comment: It is enforced when going through review and isn't a technical limitation so that shouldn't be the problem. Are you getting a 200 OK response? Also make sure you have camera write permissions enabled in your client.

Comment: yes I'm getting a 200 OK, and I have tried with both Camera read/write permissions and Camera + Images read/write permissions, same result the is_streaming field is not updated. Other fields like target temperature works fine on my app, I can write them and they are correctly updated.
Could this be related to the fact that I'm using fake cameras from the Nest Home Simulator to test with? Do you have this working on a sample app?

Comment: I tested it with a real camera, and indeed it works. So the problem is only with fake cameras from the Nest Home Simulator.  @urman, could this be fixed in the simulator? And would it be possible to get some fake video streams in home.nest.com for the fake cameras?